# SVG Snap hover over grouped elements

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, snap.svg

I have a group that contains a few elements within it:
A path (the black), and 2 rects (the pink and blue)

[image]

They all belong to the same group.

Basically, what I want to do is I want to execute a function when the group is hovered over so I do:

```
  group.hover(function(e){ //set up hovering
           console.log("hover bubble");
       }, function(e) {
           console.log("unhover bubble");
    });
```

But the way groups work is each element within the group gets that hover function...so if I hover over the black path and then move to the pink rect, it will think that is an unhover of the black path and then a hover over the pink rect..this is not what I want.

I want to just hover over the entire grouped area and have the function execute once the entire grouped area is hovered and the unhover function to execute when the entire grouped area is unhovered.

Sort of like if all of these elements were in a div, and I hovered over the div..

Comment: Sure you create a group and not a set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you have `snap.svg` and `raphael` as tags, but here is a solution using pure JS.

I made a simple SVG with a group containing a black rect (your path), a pink rect and a blue rect. When you hover over the group, it logs "hover bubble" in the console, when you hover out it logs "unhover bubble":

```js
var group = document.querySelector("g");

function isInside(node, target) {
    for (; node != null; node = node.parentNode)
      if (node == target) return true;
}

group.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    if (!isInside(event.relatedTarget, group))
      console.log("hover bubble");
});

group.addEventListener("mouseout", function(event) {
    if (!isInside(event.relatedTarget, group))
       console.log("unhover bubble");
});
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: tan;
 }
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300">
 <g>
  <rect x="40", y="40", width="220", height="220", fill="black"></rect>
  <rect x="60", y="60", width="80", height="80", fill="pink"></rect>
  <rect x="160", y="60", width="80", height="80", fill="blue"></rect>
 </g>
</svg>
```

This is the cause of your problem:

> Whenever the mouse pointer enters or leaves a node, a "mouseover" or "mouseout" event fires [...] Unfortunately, creating such an effect is not as simple as starting the effect on "mouseover" and ending it on "mouseout". When the mouse moves from a node onto one of its children, "mouseout" fires on the parent node, though the mouse did not actually leave the node’s extent. To make things worse, these events propagate just like other events, and thus you will also receive "mouseout" events when the mouse leaves one of the child nodes of the node on which the handler is registered.

Source of the code and of the quote: [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/), from Marijn Haverbeke.

Comment: Thanks for this, can you explain your code a little?

Comment: From the book: *"The isInside function follows the given node’s parent links until it either reaches the top of the document (when node becomes null) or finds the parent we are looking for"*. So, this function will return "true" when you move from a child to other child, but will return "undefined" when you enter or leave the parent. Negating undefined (using `!`) gives "true", and thus the code after `if` only runs when you enter or leave the parent element.